# Spacing after description environment

Tags: spacing, lists, description

I'm using the description environment for a list. The problem is that the text after the description list appears like this:

```
 item1
 item2
 item3
 text
text
...
```

while I want something like this:

```
 item1
 item2
 item3
text
text
...
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{outline}
\usepackage{pmgraph}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{description}
  \item[1] Schermata di benvenuto: se non risultano dati in cache, l’utente può collegarsi a un profilo esistente o crearne uno nuovo...
  \item[1.1] Registrazione
  \item[1.2] Preferenze dettagli secondari del profilo (avatar e stato)
  \item[1.3] Preferenze unità di misura e inserimento dati iniziali
  \item[1.4] Definizione del calendario: sincronizza con il calendario preferito e inserisce le prime attività
  \item[1.5] Preferenze circa le letture tematiche
  \item[1.6] Preferenze circa la privacy
  \item[1.7] Schermata di configurazione
\end{description}

\section{Sezione 2. Schermate principali}
Inoltre, per rispettare il principio di Auto descrizione dell’\textbf{ISO 9241-110}, %
sono state evitate del tutto le funzioni nascoste accessibili con tap prolungato. %
Infatti, tutte le azioni sono state associate a pulsanti visibili a schermo. 
\end{document}
```

Could somebody help me please?

Comment: This question is unclear because you're not showing what you have done really in your document

Comment: Seems line you need a `\noindent`

Comment: I've added the code

Comment: While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it. Also, is the problem with the text _in_ the description list, or _after_ `\end{description}`.

Comment: If your issue is with the text _within_ the description list you could use `\begin{description}[leftmargin=0pt]`, with the `enumitem` package.  In you updated code I only see indented text _within_ the description environment so this should work fine for you.

Comment: Don't use the `utf8x` option, but `utf8`.

Answer (score 2):

To get long lines in the `description` environment start at the left margin you need to add `[leftmargin=0pt]` option. So,

```
\begin{description}[leftmargin=0pt]
```

yields

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{showframe}
\begin{document}
\begin{description}[leftmargin=0pt]
  \item[1] Schermata di benvenuto: se non risultano dati in cache, l’utente può collegarsi a un profilo esistente o crearne uno nuovo...
  \item[1.1] Registrazione
  \item[1.2] Preferenze dettagli secondari del profilo (avatar e stato)
  \item[1.3] Preferenze unità di misura e inserimento dati iniziali
  \item[1.4] Definizione del calendario: sincronizza con il calendario preferito e inserisce le prime attività
  \item[1.5] Preferenze circa le letture tematiche
  \item[1.6] Preferenze circa la privacy
  \item[1.7] Schermata di configurazione
\end{description}

\section{Sezione 2. Schermate principali}
Inoltre, per rispettare il principio di Auto descrizione dell’\textbf{ISO 9241-110}, %
sono state evitate del tutto le funzioni nascoste accessibili con tap prolungato. %
Infatti, tutte le azioni sono state associate a pulsanti visibili a schermo. 
\end{document}
```

Comment: @barbarabeeton: I just wanted to make sure it was included. :-) Thanks for pointing that out - has been corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Your code example doesn't agree with the start of the question, but I think the problem can be illustrated by the following document:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{showframe}% just for the example
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{outline}
\usepackage{pmgraph}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}
  \item[1] Schermata di benvenuto: se non risultano dati in cache, 
           l’utente può collegarsi a un profilo esistente o crearne uno nuovo...
  \item[1.1] Registrazione
  \item[1.2] Preferenze dettagli secondari del profilo (avatar e stato)
\end{description}
This line is not indented; let's show it by
adding nonsense text so that the paragraph is
long enough to be split across lines.

\begin{description}
  \item[1] Schermata di benvenuto: se non risultano dati in cache,
           l’utente può collegarsi a un profilo esistente o crearne uno nuovo...
  \item[1.1] Registrazione
  \item[1.2] Preferenze dettagli secondari del profilo (avatar e stato)
\end{description}

This line is indented; let's show it by
adding nonsense text so that the paragraph is
long enough to be split across lines.

\end{document}
```

The paragraph after `description` is normally indented if a blank line precedes it; not if no blank line intervenes in between.

[image]